# Data getting repeated in list

Tags: android

I am using the following code to show a listview from database but in the list the data is getting repeated and shown. Heres the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView gridView;
public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "91"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "99"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "95"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "93"));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName()
                + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

    }

    db.getAllContacts();

    gridView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
    }
```

Heres is another class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));

            String name = cursor.getString(1) + "\n" + cursor.getString(2);
            MainActivity.ArrayofName.add(name);
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

    }
```

Please tell me why the data is being repeated. As you can see only four contacts are added but the list is showing around 40 contacts with those four repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every time you running this app , you are inserting value every time. That's why you are getting repeated values.So before you inserting values to your database either clear your database or use shared preference and insert data to database in first run only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try and tell the results

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes in ur code:

In Databasehandler.java:
make return type void & make changes in the function getAllContacts() accordingly

In MainActivity.java:
comment the following part..:

```
// Reading all contacts
Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

for (Contact cn : contacts) {
    String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName()
            + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
    // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);

}
```